# Powershell Scripts for users

Tags: powershell, signing

I am trying to distribute a Powershell script for our users to update some files in their roaming profile. The script works fine but I'm hitting the issue where some machines have Powershell scripts disabled.

I am having them download this from a FTP server and run it from their desktop.

Is there a way to allow them to run the script and not have it blocked by Windows?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As an Administrator, you can set the execution policy by typing this into your PowerShell window:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned -Scope CurrentUser
```

When you are done updating everything, you can set the policy back to its default value with:

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

You can bypass this policy for a single script by adding `-ExecutionPolicy Bypass` when running powershell

```
powershell -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File script.ps1
```

Comment: Hey. Thank you for your response. These are users that don't have access to the admin account and I don't have access to the machines (I wouldn't need the script if I did). It's pretty simple and just updates email signatures with a new hyperlink.

Is there a way to have them do this without admin or my intervention? They are mostly computer illiterate.

Comment: One way that you can try and avoid it is by creating a seperate script which references your original script: `Get-Content "c:\temp\test.ps1" | PowerShell.exe -noprofile - ` this technique does not result in a configuration change, but does require writing your script to to their computer. However, you could read it from a network share if you’re trying to avoid putting the script on their PC.

Comment: Well I was able to get around it by making a batch file that downloaded and ran the PowerShell script with the -ExecutionPolicy Bypass parameter. I'll take that as the solution. Thank you for your help. In general though, I have no idea how to distribute and run powershell files for our users without this convoluted process. Any tips on that in general? Thanks again!